# spring-ws-test: How to mock a SoapFaultDetail

Tags: java, spring-ws

With spring-ws-test how can I mock a SoapFaultDetail to return the expected error payload?

[ResponseCreators](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/test/client/ResponseCreators.html) seems to support only faultString/ faultReason:

```
mockServer.expect(anything()).andRespond(withClientOrSenderFault(faultStringOrReason, Locale.GERMAN));
```

The detail element is not set. I need the fault to contain my custom payload however.

Is there a high-level API to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `withPayload` method of `ResponseCreators` and provide it with a SOAP fault that contains your custom payload as shown below:

```
    Source faultPayload = new StringSource(
            "<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:v1=\"http://domain/schema/common/fault\">"
                    + "<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>"
                    + "<faultstring xml:lang=\"en\">fault</faultstring>"
                    + "<detail>"
                    + "<v1:custompayload>"
                    + "<v1:element1>element1</v1:element1>"
                    + "<v1:element2>element2</v1:element2>"
                    + "</v1:custompayload>" 
                    + "</detail>"
                    + "</SOAP-ENV:Fault>");

    mockWebServiceServer.expect(payload(requestPayload))
            .andRespond(withPayload(faultPayload));
```

Comment: This seems to set the envelop as payload, which is wrong.

Comment: withSoapEnvelope can be used though

Comment: Could you explain why the above is wrong? 'withPayload' does not set the envelop as payload, it sets the given Resource XML as payload response (content of the SOAP body element). In the case of a SOAP fault this would be a SOAP Fault element in the soap envelope namespace (as shown above). In my Unit test cases, the above triggers a SoapFaultClientException and I'm able to get the FaultDetail and unmarshal the custom content to the correct object.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm using now a StreamSource which reads a SOAP message that includes the envelop. Unfortunately, my vote is locked until you edit your answer.

Comment: Nice to hear that it works. I edited the answer so the vote should now be unlocked.